# How return list with inner list in SQL?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, relations

I prepared following SQL statement:

```
SELECT tasks.name, profiles.email, types.specification,
    tasks.description, tasks.attachment_link, tasks.priority,
    assigned_tasks.progress_details, assigned_tasks.activation_date,
    assigned_tasks.expired_date  
FROM profiles, types, tasks, assigned_tasks 
WHERE profiles.id = assigned_tasks.profile_id 
AND assigned_tasks.task_id = tasks.id 
AND types.id = tasks.type_id
ORDER BY tasks.name;
```

I want show in view gruped tasks with assigned email. Something like this:

[image]

[image]

I see records with single assignments, task names are duplicated. I want to show e-mail list in owner cell in table - it is possible?

Python return touples:

```
('Backend', 'agnieszka.lasota1@gmail.com', 'Database managment', 'Create serwer full backend and copy data to SSD 1TB', 'NULL', 2, 'to do - 0% progress', datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 10, 18, 36), None)
('call to customer', 'wolnygosc@interia.pl', 'IT online support', 'answer for questions about cloud', 'https://dianet.pl/cloud/index.html', 1, 'TO DO', datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 14, 57, 23), None)
```

I want something like that:

```
('Backend', ('agnieszka.lasota1@gmail.com', 'wolnygosc@interia.pl'), 'Database managment', 'Create serwer full backend and copy data to SSD 1TB', 'NULL', 2, 'to do - 0% progress', datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 10, 18, 36), None)
```

Two users might be assign to one task I want show it in HTML table. How split records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`.
Use the `JOIN .. ON` syntax instead of the old syntax.

```
SELECT  tasks.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(profiles.email) AS emails,
        types.specification,
        tasks.description, tasks.attachment_link, tasks.priority,
        ats.progress_details, ats.activation_date, ats.expired_date  
    FROM profiles AS p
    JOIN assigned_tasks AS ats  ON ats.profile_id = p.id
    JOIN tasks  ON tasks.id = ats.task_id
    JOIN types  ON types.id = tasks.type_id
    GROUP BY tasks.name,
             types.specification,
             tasks.description, tasks.attachment_link, tasks.priority,
             ats.progress_details, ats.activation_date, ats.expired_date  
    ORDER BY tasks.name;
```

Instead of `datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 10, 18, 36)`, simply use

```
"2021-06-01 10:18:26"
```

Or you could use this, if you simply want the current date and time:

```
NOW()
```